# Qual o comando em linux para copiar o conteudo de uma pasta para outra pasta

Tags: linux

eu tentei o seguinte comando

```
cp -avr origem destino
```

O problema é que o comando cria uma pasta dentro do destino e la dentro o conteudo.

O que eu pretendo é o conteudo directamente na pasta sem que crie outra pasta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dessa forma você está levando a pasta com os arquivos que tem dentro. Tente dessa forma para levar somente os arquivos.

```
cp caminhoDaPasta/* caminhoDoDestino/
```

O `*` indica que todos os arquivos serão copiados.

Comment: apareceu  omitting directory

Comment: resolvi usando  cp -avr  caminhoDaPasta/* caminhoDoDestino/